# Error code 121 In Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application:

```
(Error code 121) In Google app engine
```

I am using standard app engine versions mentioned below:

> Google Cloud SDK 200.0.0
>   alpha 2018.04.30
>   app-engine-python 1.9.69
>   app-engine-python-extras 1.9.69

Why am I getting `121`  error code? Thanks for your hints.

Comment: What's the request log for that request? What's the code handling that request?

Comment: What environment are you using?

Comment: Standard app engine @J.LValtueña

Comment: It is failing always or only sometimes?

Comment: while processing high load data , it is failing